# Saving business rules per user

Tags: c#, sql

```
public interface IRule
{
    bool Check(string input);
}
```

I have an interface that defines a rule.  A rule is just a generic business rule or constraint that a user can create.  So I have two sample rules:

```
public class ContainsRule : IRule
{
    public string MustContain { get; set; }

    public bool Check(string input)
    {
        return input.Contains(this.MustContain);
    }
}

public class LengthRule : IRule
{
    public int MaxLength { get; set; }

    public bool Check(string input)
    {
        return input.Length <= this.MaxLength;
    }
}
```

Rules may have more than one property that can be set, but in this example, each of these rules only have one property.

A user can create their own set of rules that should be saved.  For example, a user have these three rules:

```
IRule[] rules = new IRule[]
{
    new ContainsRule { MustContain = "foo" },
    new ContainsRule { MustContain = "bar" },
    new LengthRule { MaxLength = 5}
};
```

I need to persist this information to a database or some data store for each user.  Since each user can have their own set of rules, I'm not sure what the database tables should look like.

```
User  |  ClassName               |  Parameters
-----------------------------------------------
1     |  Namespace.ContainsRule  |  MustContain:foo
1     |  Namespace.ContainsRule  |  MustContain:bar
1     |  Namespace.LengthRule    |  MaxLength:5
```

My initial guess would be to create a table that looks something like the above, where parameters should a string.  This means I would need to parse out the information and use reflection or something to set the properties.  I would need to use the activator to create the class using the ClassName column.  Another suggestion was instead of creating a delimited string for all the properties, there would be another table.  Each of the properties would be its own row that has a foreign key relationship back to a row in the table above.

However, both examples don't seem to be the best way of saving these rules.  Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use XML serialisation.  The database table would contain the User # and the XML serialisation of the indvidual rule.

Comment: When I deserialize the rules, I need to instantiate XmlSerializer.  XmlSerializer's constructor requires a type.  Since I'm referring to each of these rules as an interface (IRule), how do I know the type that I'm deserializing?

Comment: You can have a base type and specify all the allowed subtypes when you setup the XmlSerializer. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e5aakyae.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are retrieving from database.
If so, try my suggestion.

Store the retrieved data into datatable, or convert them to datatable before applying the rule.
So the rule can be put as normal sql in datatable's filter property.
Instead of rule name and parameters, you can change it to a column containing
   `column like '%foo%'`

Then apply this on the datatable's filter.

PS: I have converted List to Datatable and used such filter before

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me, simply put, you need to map your objects to SQL tables (if only there was a technology that could to do this automatically... :)

Based on what you have posted, I envisage at least six SQL tables, more if there are further subclasses of rule e.g.

- Rules
- MustContainTextRules (subclass of Rules, 1:0..m)
- MaxLengthRules (subclass of Rules, 1:0..1)
- [Possibily further subclasses of Rules e.g. MinLengthRules?]
- Rulesets ("a set of Rules")
- Users
- RulesetOwnership (relationship table between Users and Rulesets)

Whether they are distinct tables may be influenced by whether the rules are interrelated e.g. if the `MinLengthRule` value for a `Ruleset` cannot exceed its `MaxLengthRule` value then you may find it difficult to write a SQL constraint to validate this when they are in different tables.